# What is Big O in this example of code, O(N) or O(N^2)?

Tags: python, algorithm

Can you please explain what is Big O in this example of code?

```
arr = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1]
]

def count_ones(outer_array):
  count = 0
  for inner_array in outer_array:
    for number in inner_array:
      count += 1
  return count

count_ones(arr)
```

Comment: It's O(N) where N is the total number of elements in the 2-dimensional list.

Comment: You already have your answer, you've counted the number of operations in the variable `count`

Comment: When you say an algorithm takes O(N) or O(N²), it's important to specify what is N. Otherwise the statement doesn't really make sense. However, in many situations, there is only one reasonable thing we could call N, so people omit to specify it. But if there is the slightest ambiguity, you should specify it.

Comment: @Stef Thanks, I am noobie, I did not know that is important to specify what is N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on your definition of `n`. If you define `n` to be the number of cells in the 2d matrix, then this nested loop is of linear complexity `O(n)` in relation to it.

On the other hand, if you define `n` to be the length of the outer array and `m` the maximum length of the inner arrays then the time complexity is `O(n*m)`.

Either way, the complexity can't be `O(n^2)` since in that case it needs to be a square matrix with sides of equal length `n`.

Comment: Thank you. So I always need to specify what is N first to make correct answer about complexity?

Comment: Yes. In some cases it may be obvious but if it's not, like in this case, you need to specify what the variables used in Big O mean to avoid confusion @HelloPlanetEarth

Answer (score 0):

Given that n is defined as the total number of elements in the nested array:

```
  for inner_array in outer_array:
    for number in inner_array:
```

is O(n) since it visits every element once.

```
count += 1
```

is O(1) since it is basic arithmetic.

O(1) * O(n) = O(n)

Comment: "Given that n is defined as the total number of elements in the nested array" is somewhat misleading. The OP **can** define *n* to be the total number of elements. Also, in the OP's question there was an *N* but no *n*.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have 2-dimension array and every element picks once.
In common case it's O(N), where N - number of elements.